# Possible to somehow override a container's padding?

Tags: css, html, padding

I could be way overthinking this but I'm working with Wordpress for the first time and getting used to everything is giving me a major headache.

Basically, I have a container div. I'm lazy and put a 10px padding. But for the theme I'm *trying* to create, I have a couple of `divs` that I want to span the entire container, without the padding.

Here's a picture example:

[image]

Is there a way to bypass the container div's settings so this one bar won't be padded?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add negative margins on the divs that should span the entire container:

```
div { margin-right: -10px; margin-left: -10px; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Negative margins are your friend here.

```
.wide-child{
    margin: 0 -10px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/post_erasmus/fgfXY/)

Answer (score 2):

Try using a negative margin on the inside div.

Answer (score 1):

```
.nopadding {
   width: 100vw;
   position: relative;
   left:49%;
   right:49%;
   margin-left: -50vw;
   margin-right: -50vw; 
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/